# Unit Test - Mockito gives NullPointerException when mocking an interface

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

I have a presenter, which has a method getView() that returns a view. The view, which implements MyView (an interface), has a method isActive which indicates whether it is active.

I am testing the presenter.

In the @Before setup of the testClass, I initialize the presenter.

testClass.java:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class testClass {
    private Presenter presenter;
    @Mock
    private MyView mockView;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    presenter = new Presenter(mockView);
    when(mockView.isActive()).thenReturn(true);
}

@Test
public void testIsActive() {
    presenter.isViewActive();
    verify(mockView).isActive();
}
```

Presenter.java:

```
public class Presenter {
    private MyView view;

    // The following view is an instance of MyView, not View (typo before).
    public Presenter(MyView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public boolean isViewActive() {
        return getView().isActive();
    }

    public MyView getView() {
        return view;
    }

}
```

MyView.class:

```
public interface MyView {
    boolean isActive();
}
```

However, the above code would generate NullPointerException when

```
presenter.isViewActive();
```

is running.

Why is it?

And when I replace

```
@Mock
private MyView mockView;
```

with

```
@Mock
private ConcreteMyView mockView;
```

where ConcreteMyView is an implementation of interface MyView, the code runs smoothly.

Any hints?

Comment: I see that in Presenter, you take View as the constructor parameter. But your definition of MyView does not extend from View, so it doesn't compile (cannot set this.view to View instance). Is this a typo in the code?

Comment: Note, when I change View to MyView in the Presenter constructor, the testcase compiles and runs successfully for me

Answer (score 0):

I mdewit already identified your tested class is taking a View (not shown/defined) instead of MyView.

If you have problem you can look in the code below and compare.

```
public class SomeTest {
  private Presenter presenter;
  @Mock
  private MyView mockView;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    presenter = new Presenter(mockView);
    when(mockView.isActive()).thenReturn(true);
  }

  @Test
  public void testIsActive() {
    assertTrue(presenter.isViewActive());
    verify(mockView).isActive();
  }

  private class Presenter {
    private MyView view;

    public Presenter(MyView view) {
      this.view = view;
    }

    public boolean isViewActive() {
      return getView().isActive();
      //return true;
    }

    public MyView getView() {
      return view;
    }
  }

  private interface MyView {
    boolean isActive();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the answer until recently. 
So you are inferring that when mocking the interface MyView, since it is not a concrete class, Mockito is trying to mock its super class, which is a concrete class, instead? So it means we cannot mock an interface right?

Comment: No, definitely not. It's actually a good practice mocking interfaces and it's what I pasted in the code above. ( MyView is an interface and its being mocked ) . The only problem of your code is that you are using another class called 'View' ( Look in 'Presenter' constructor parameter ).

Comment: I noticed. Sorry, it was just a typo, in the actual case, the view taken in the Presenter constructor is actually an instance of MyView. So your answer is not correct